# Is There a Good Way to Compile Solidity on the Frontend?

Tags: solidity, remix

By using web3deploy on remix, it is one click to copy, and one click function for you to allow someone on the the frontend to deploy a contract you are hosting via MetaMask.

If you wanted to make that contract variable, so the `data: {bytecode}` field could vary based on some variables in the Solidity code, you would need to compile it and then update the `data:` field of your web3.js deployment.

Is there a way to make solc work on the frontend? Is there a service that lets you compile Solidity remotely?

Update: I got Eric Tang's project to compile in the browser, but I haven't figured out how to only output the bytecode, nor what regex to turn the solidity contract code into one big string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Remix just uses [`solc-js`](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js). You could do the same.

**EDIT**

You might want [`browser-solc`](https://github.com/ericxtang/browser-solc), which is a "browserified" version of `solc-js`.

**EDIT 2**

Example usage:

```
<script src="browser-solc.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  BrowserSolc.loadVersion("soljson-v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.js", function (compiler) {
    var source = 'pragma solidity ^0.4.20;\ncontract Test { function Test() public { } }';
    var contract = compiler.compile(source, 0).contracts[':Test'];
    console.log(contract.bytecode);
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer works already, though not yet the way I want, which is to just get the bytecode. The docs are not great, so I will definitely share my project once finished.

Comment: I'm having difficulty locating the method in the browser-solc. It's lightweight, but I just need the bytecode. Throwing random methods at the wall, but still only get JSON output of everything. 

I wish there was some documentation on the remix implementation of these features. They are parsing all of it. So am going to comb through that. There's absolutely no notes in any of these projects! It's crazy, taped together functions that jump all over.

Comment: The bytecode is in the JSON. I added working code.

Comment: Perfect! I wish I could figure out how this works, but thankfully it just does. I was resigned to parsing the mess of JSON after hearing some other answers. Minifying the code into a string seems to work as well as newline tags, I just took out the double quotes from my contract. Going to concatenate the variable terms, and make this work.

Comment: All I did was log the JSON and search for "bytecode".